# Inserting an URL in android studio

Tags: android-studio

i have an existing project, it's a quiz app and i want to put a button that sends the user to a web site if he gets the wrong answer and wants to get infomations on the correct answer and i want to know how to do it

Answer (score 2):

first check the answer is correct or not. if is it right use condition like

```
if(answer){ // answer is true
    // todo
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}else{
   // todo
}
```